# Python Jupyter Notebook: Make Image in Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am creating a plot using p = figure(...), however when I run

> show(p)

the plot opens up a new window. How do I make it appear in the notebook?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are plotting with Matplotlib, you can run this line at the beginning, or just before you start plotting:

```
%matplotlib inline
```